# Haskell : understand Functor

Tags: haskell, functor

I am doing an Haskell tutorial about Applicative Functor :
[CIS194: Homework10 - applicative](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis194/spring13/hw/10-applicative.pdf)

In the tutorial, the below parser is given:

```
-- A parser for a value of type a is a function which takes a String
-- representing the input to be parsed, and succeeds or fails; if it
-- succeeds, it returns the parsed value along with the remainder of
-- the input.
newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }
```

On exercise 2, we are asked to implement an Applicative instance for Parser.
Before implementing Applicative, we need to implement Functor.
My Functor Parser implementation is :

```
instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f p = Parser ( -- take a function and a parser
    \s0 -> case runParser p s0 of -- parse a string
        Nothing -> Nothing -- if parse fails, returns nothing
        Just (a,s1) -> Just (f a,s1) -- if parse succeed, returns
                                      --1. 1st function applied to parsed result
                                      --2. remaining string
    )
```

However i found anoter way to implement this Functor :
 [bschwb /cis194-solutions](https://github.com/bschwb/cis194-solutions/blob/master/10-applicative-functors-part1/AParser.hs)
The Functor Parser implementation is :

```
first :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
first f (a, c) = (f a, c)

instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f (Parser rp) = Parser (fmap (first f) . rp)
```

I do not understand the '. rp' part, can you please help me ?
To my understanding :

- Parser rp : 'rp' can be anything (Integer, tuple, function ...) and we are not supposed to know what it is;
- The '.' operator applies only to functions;
- So we can not mix '.' and 'rp' because we are not sure 'rp' will be a function.
  What did I miss or misunderstand ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is a *functor*, not a *fonctor*, you consequently use the wrong name :)

Comment: Thank you William. I mixed English 'functor' with French 'foncteur'. My bad :(

Comment: `rp` is a function of type `String -> Maybe (a, String)`, which is the type of the argument to the `Parser` constructor. It is only the `a` type variable in that type which could be anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }`, I was focusing on the data type `Parser a`, and not on the constructor `Parser :: (String -> Maybe (a, String)) -> Parser a`.

Now this is clear:

```
instance Functor Parser where
    fmap -- Functor f => (a->b) -> f a -> f b
      func -- a -> b
      (Parser rp) -- regarding Parser constructor rp :: String -> Maybe (a, String)
     = Parser
      (
        fmap (first func) -- we can deduce : fmap (first func) :: Functor f => f (a, c) -> f (func a, c)
        . -- and we know : (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
        rp -- rp :: String -> Maybe (a, String)
      ) -- therefore : fmap (first func).rp :: String -> Maybe (func a, String)
```

Thanks duplode for his comment.